# Change space between bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to set up proper spaces between bars in my ggplot.

That's how it looks like:

[image]

That's data:

```
> dput(tbl_all_ribosomes_abundance_overlap_dat)
structure(list(Ribosome = c("Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", 
"Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", 
"Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", 
"Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", 
"Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", 
"Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", 
"Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", 
"Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", 
"Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", 
"Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", 
"Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", 
"Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", 
"Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", 
"Cytosol", "Plastid", "Plastid", "Cytosol", "Cytosol"), Size_ranges = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 84L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 165L, 
165L, 165L, 165L, 199L, 199L, 199L, 199L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 433L, 433L, 433L, 
433L, 506L, 506L, 506L, 506L, 581L, 581L, 581L, 581L, 652L, 652L, 
652L, 652L, 733L, 733L, 733L, 733L, 818L, 818L, 818L, 818L, 896L, 
896L, 896L, 896L, 972L, 972L, 972L, 972L, 1039L, 1039L, 1039L, 
1039L), Abundance = c(15236000, 36722900, 8953800, 8975200, 45971100, 
99067800, 20305100, 26360500, 91416000, 219396000, 71722610, 
84034100, 230630600, 254380400, 52402800, 50422300, 354388700, 
437609200, 72343800, 86587600, 462991400, 497156100, 51817210, 
65168400, 235045400, 290932300, 41362400, 50220300, 168440600, 
196797700, 107294900, 158465800, 362305500, 375372400, 158236400, 
209906300, 1367158670, 1122186600, 203436000, 203426900, 978435120, 
983735500, 373804400, 362937700, 2104276960, 2220253960, 394261700, 
410656800, 1267607300, 1323143500, 285954000, 276834600, 1080187900, 
1410693500, 1261120700, 1299253600, 840738200, 1226346700, 1591379300, 
1829220400, 1139340100, 1758611700, 2003838200, 2346221200, 2425368000, 
3150723500, 2658315400, 3184999800, 3141234200, 4124976700, 3484620300, 
4111995200, 2880830100, 4403308600, 4233078100, 4960194500, 2923459800, 
4360192600, 5238580300, 5494148500), Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("EOD", 
"EON"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Ribosome", "Size_ranges", 
"Abundance", "Time"), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = "data.frame")
```

That's the code which I use for plotting:

```
ggplot(data=tbl_all_ribosomes_abundance_overlap_dat, mapping=aes(x=Size_ranges, y=Abundance, fill=Time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", width = 25) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1000), 
                     breaks = c(0, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000)) +
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("EOD" = "gold1", "EON" = "gray")) +
  facet_grid(Ribosome~.)
```

As you see on the left side of the graph it does look messy because space between bars do not exist. Space between bars on the right side is, from the other hand, too big. Do you have any idea how I can improve this graph by increasing and decreasing spaces in specific places ?

Suggestions regarding setting up different scale for y axis to make it more clear (left side) are more than welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the x-variable discrete instead of continuous. You consider the values as categorical instead of numeric. This would make an evenly spaced bar for each of the values.

```
library(dplyr)
tbl_all_ribosomes_abundance_overlap_dat %>% 
  mutate(Size_ranges = factor(Size_ranges)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Size_ranges, y=Abundance, fill=Time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("EOD" = "gold1", "EON" = "gray")) +
  facet_grid(Ribosome~.) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like a good solution. Do you have any idea how I could make the bars on the left side more visible ? What kind of scale could I use ?

Comment: Well, these values are just very low compared to the other values, there is not much to do about that. If these values have a special meaning, you might consider split the data in two and make two separate plots.